# Change type to non-null after validation

Tags: typescript

Lets say I have the following code

```
const publicPath: string | undefined = config.output && config.output.publicPath
invariant(publicPath, "No publicPath for config: ${config}")
// declare const publicPath: string // error
```

I know that after `invariant` `publicPath` will be non-empty (program will halt if so), how to say that to typescript?

---

even this doesnt work

```
function invariant<T>(s: T | undefined | null, msg): s is T | never {
    if (!s)
        throw new Error(msg)
    return true
}


const publicPath: string | undefined = '/* ... */'
invariant(publicPath, "No publicPath for config: ${config}")
// publicPath still string
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the not-null assertion operator (`!`) to assert that a variable is not null and not undefined:

```
const publicPath: string | undefined = config.output && config.output.publicPath
invariant(publicPath, "No publicPath for config: ${config}")

const nonNullPublicPath: string = publicPath!
```

Comment: thanks to all guys, all answers are valid, I think I will use this one, cause I can have multiple validations

Answer (score 1):

You could declare a new variable, with a more strict type:

```
const configuredPublicPath: string | undefined = config.output && config.output.publicPath

const publicPath: string = invariant(configuredPublicPath,
                                                     "No publicPath for config: ${config}")
```

[Playground demo link here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=function%20invariant(publicPath%2C%20msg)%3A%20string%20%7B%20return%20%22%22%20%7D%3B%0D%0Alet%20config%20%3D%20%7B%20output%3A%20%7B%20publicPath%3A%20%22%22%20%7D%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20configuredPublicPath%3A%20string%20%7C%20undefined%20%3D%20config.output%20%26%26%20config.output.publicPath%0D%0Aconst%20publicPath%3A%20string%20%3D%20invariant(configuredPublicPath%2C%20%22No%20publicPath%20for%20config%3A%20%24%7Bconfig%7D%22)%3B#src=function%20invariant(publicPath%2C%20msg)%3A%20string%20%7B%20return%20%22%22%20%7D%3B%0D%0Alet%20config%20%3D%20%7B%20output%3A%20%7B%20publicPath%3A%20%22%22%20%7D%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20configuredPublicPath%3A%20string%20%7C%20undefined%20%3D%20config.output%20%26%26%20config.output.publicPath%0D%0Aconst%20publicPath%3A%20string%20%3D%20invariant(configuredPublicPath%2C%20%22No%20publicPath%20for%20config%3A%20%24%7Bconfig%7D%22)%3B) (make sure you click `Options -> strictNullChecks`).

Answer (score 1):

Not possible.

You can do:

```
const publicPath: string | undefined = /* ... */
invariant(publicPath, "No publicPath for config: ${config}")
const publicPath2 = publicPath as string
```

Or, I suggest:

```
function invariant(s: string | undefined, msg): string {
    if (!s)
        throw new Error(msg)
    return s
}
const publicPath = invariant(config.output && config.output.publicPath, "No publicPath for config: ${config}")
```

Notice: Use generics if the config types are not all strings:

```
function invariant<T>(s: T | undefined, msg): T {
    if (!s)
        throw new Error(msg)
    return s
}
```